# how to get status of disable and enable button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to get the status of disable and enable buttons in jQuery. I make disable and enable function, but I need to know how to get the status of the enable and disable button.

```
function disableButtons(){
    $('#saveButtonID').attr('src', 'Export-Realtime_disable.png');
    $('#searchID').attr('src', 'search_disable.png');
    $('#emailID').attr('src', 'Email-Document_disable.png');
    $('#saveButtonID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#searchID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#emailID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}

function enableButtons(){
    $('#saveButtonID').attr('src', 'Export-Realtime.png');
    $('#searchID').attr('src', 'search.png');
    $('#emailID').attr('src', 'Email-Document.png');
    $('#saveButtonID').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#searchID').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#emailID').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');


}
```

How would I get the status of the given button, is it disabled or enabled?

```
alert(''+ $('#searchID').attr('disabled'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Below will return true or false

```
$('#searchID').is(':disabled');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#searchID").is(":disabled")
```

OR

```
$('#searchID').prop('disabled')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NZf6r/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("#searchId").is(":disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither from answers above work for my button with disabled attribute, that's why I do this check:

```
$('#myBtnId').attr('disabled') === 'undefined') {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.is()` operator to check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

[HERE](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var chek = $("#searchID").is(":disabled")
alert(chek);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLJmT/)